# Как автоматически сформировать путь?

Tags: php, yii, yii2

Как можно реализовать чтоб при переходе на контролер не указав никаких параметров формировался некий путь!

Например когда пользователь вводит в командную строку `http://user/index?id=` или `http://user/index?` автоматически формировался путь `http://user/index?id=mainpage&user=1`

**Какими средствами такое реализовуется ?**

Действие

```
public function actionIndex()
    {
        $currentUser = null;
        if (Yii::$app->user->isGuest || Yii::$app->request->isGet) {
            if ($id = Yii::$app->request->get('id')) {
                $currentUser = User::find()->where(['nick_name' => $id])->one();
            }
        }
        if (!Yii::$app->user->isGuest ) {
            if (Yii::$app->request->get('id') == Yii::$app->user->identity->nick_name || Yii::$app->request->get('id') ==  null ) {
                $currentUser = User::find()->where(['nick_name' => Yii::$app->user->identity->nick_name])->one();
            }
        }
        return $this->render('index', [
            'currentUser' => $currentUser,
        ]);
    }
```

Comment: Независимо от параметров? Или для конкретно выше указанных условий? Опишите конкретно задачу как заказчик, а не как программист. Может предложим вариант куда лучше

Comment: @UrmuzTagizade, когда пользователь переходит по ссылке на свою страницу в строке запроса должна формироваться строка того вида, которою я привел в примере! Но даже когда пользователь введет просто название контроллера плюс экшен - все равно должна  формироваться строка вида  `http://user/index?id=mainpage&user=1` с его данными

Comment: скиньте кусок кода контроллера с действием

Comment: @UrmuzTagizade, кинул действие

Comment: Просто сделай редирект на другой урл. в акшене котнтроллера.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если вы хотите чтобы путь формировался именно в строке браузера, то используйте redirect:

```
return $this->redirect(['user/index', 'id' => 'mainpage', 'user' => 1]);
```

---

**TL;DR;**

Если же вас интересуют параметры по-умолчанию, то можно это сделать либо через routing либо прямо в конроллере.

**Параметры по-умолчанию через routing**

В конфиге приложения:

```
$config = [
    'components' => [
        'urlManager' => [
            'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
            'showScriptName' => false,
            'rules' => [
                // other rules
                ['verb' => 'GET', 'pattern' => 'user/index', 'route' => 'user/index', 'defaults' => ['id' => 'mainpage', 'user' => 1]],
            ]
        ]
    ],
];
```

**Параметры по-умолчанию в контроллере**

Позволю себе предположить, что `$currentUser` нужно все-таки искать по параметру `$user`

```
$input = DynamicModel::validateData([
    'id' => \Yii::$app->request->get('id', 'mainpage'), // вторым параметром -- значение по-умолчанию
    'user' => \Yii::$app->request->get('user', \Yii::$app->user->isGuest ? '1' : \Yii::$app->user->identity->nick_name),
    // тут вторым параметром идет значение по-умолчанию, которое зависит от условия
    // через routing так сделать не получится
], [
    ['user', 'exist', 'targetClass' => User::className(), 'targetAttribute' => 'nick_name'],
    // можно добавить другие валидаторы
    // http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-input-validation.html#ad-hoc-validation
]);

if ($input->hasErrors()) {
    // что-нибудь на случай ошибки, например redirect на 404
}

return $this->render('index', [
    'currentUser' => User::findOne(['nick_name' => $input->user]),
    'id' => $input->id
    // это как я понимаю page ID, так что здесь скорее будет что-то типа Page::findOne($input->id)
    // ну и соответствующий валидатор тогда нужен выше
]);
```

Я бы рекомендовал конечно второй вариант, т.к. тут есть возможность настраивать параметры по-умолчанию более гибко.

Хочу также обратить внимание, что в вашем коде много... странностей:

1. параметр `user` в контроллере никак не используется (если только вы его не обрабатываете как-то в роутинге, что вряд-ли)
2. `currentUser` ищется по параемтру `id` который семантически означает `nick_name`
3. не авторизованный пользователь может зайти на страницу с любым `id`, а авторизованный --  только на свою
4. если неавторизованным пользователем передан не корректный `id` , то отобразится view с `$currentUser === null` (для авторизованного пользователя такая ситуация будет всегда если `$id` не пуст и не равен `nick_name` текущего пользователя)
5. неавторизованным пользователям разрешается искать `$currentUser` тольео через HTTP метод `GET`, авторизованным -- с помощью любого HTTP метода

Часть этих странностей исправлена в предложенном выше примере.